# Saving timestamps in a MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to save a lot of dates in a MySQL server, and want to be able to get a range of them out quickly. So my idea is to save them as integers, and then just use `<` and `>` to get then back out.

My concern is can I always rely on php to always be able to make them readable again, like `2007-04-24 15:23:42` without making changing the date

Comment: store dates as (a)date type always

Comment: Why can't you just use the normal [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) type column? Storing them as numbers is **annoying** and will prove to be an immediately unpopular decision. These can be compared with range operators like `>` or `<` and `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL essentially stores Datetimes as 8 byte integers anyways, I don't see a need to convert them back and forth.

If you do need to convert them, as long as you cast them back and forth consistently you should be fine.

Comment: The reason why I need to convert them back is to make them readable for a java program, and for humans.

Comment: Umm... JDBC automatically handles this conversion for you, using getDate() or getTimestamp(), and as for formatting, you can use SimpleDateFormat to make them human readable.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to store them as integers at all. What's wrong with storing them as DateTime in MySQL? You can still easily pull out a given range because the backend just uses integers.